# Matrices such that $M+M^T$ is positive-definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Suppose that $M$ is a real square matrix, and that $M+M^T$ is positive-definite. Do $M$'s eigenvalues all have positive real parts?

Any references/proofs/counterexamples are welcomed.

Comment: I believe that is only in the case that it is p.s.d; positive semi-definite.

Comment: And $M$ must be Hermitian